# Using Mysql/sqlite to store mercurial login info/permissions

Tags: database, mercurial, permissions

Let me preface this a bit with: I know very very little python. With that said...

I would like to store permissions for Mercurial repos (pull and push rights) in a database for easy editing in a web app / via API. I've done some googling but I guess my google-foo isn't as good as I thought it was because I came up blank. I was wondering if anyone has done this / knows of a open source project that does it to save me some time. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps take a look at [RhodeCode](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/). I haven't used it myself, but believe it is something like that you want.